# How to extend a public wifi?

Tags: networking, authentication, repeater, wireless-extender

So I moved in a new building which provides internet like hotels. It's a public network without password you connect to then it forwards you to a page you need to provide your username and password.

What I need is to extend this network so I can use the same account that I logged into on different devices and to use it on LAN so I can connect my NAS and whatever.

using normal repeater won't work cuz it doesn't deal with Enterprise authentication.

Is there any idea that I can do? Is there a repeater with a browser where u can do the authentication?

Comment: Note that login via web browser is _not_ WPA Enterprise authentication – it's MAC-based "captive portal" authentication.

Comment: You need to ask the Landlord if your request is feasible and if so, how you would do it. You cannot connect an infrastructure to your machine connected as described above.

Comment: @user1686 I read that somewhere that is Enterprise authentication where you are required to provide username and password.

Comment: @John the landlord is too old and he had no idea. Can't I connect to the network wirelessly and log in using my desktop then tether the connection using the ethernet port of my desktop to another AP?

Comment: @Nano: Yes and no. It means _one specific way_ of providing username and password -- if it were WPA-Enterprise, then you'd see Windows itself show you a username/password dialog before connecting (kinda like it shows one for regular wifi passphrases), and not a browser page after connecting.

Comment: If this is a long term proposition and the Landlord will not help, you may need to provide your own Internet (Cellular Hotspot with Ethernet ports to connect a network). I have done this in a couple of places.

Answer (score 0):

On your laptop or PC, try changing your wireless MAC address to one that starts with one of these, and see if you still need to use the authentication page:

```
X-Box One       50:1A:C5, 28:18:78, 60:45:BD

PlayStation 4   B0:05:94, 70:9E:29

Wii U           34:AF:2C
```

If that works, you can then get a wireless router compatible with DD-WRT, change its wireless MAC to something similar, then put it in wireless bridge mode.  This will share the wireless connection among the devices Ethernet ports.

Comment: It still forwards me to the login page :(